# Azure Data Factory: How to trigger same pipeline after its completion

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can i trigger same pipeline after its completion

> I have tried with schedule trigger but when i gave 20hr as interval
> it is finishing sometimes in 16hr sometimes 17hrs I am not certain
> about hours so I gave 20hr but 3 to 4 hours are being wasted for next
> run

Please help me how can I trigger right after pipeline status is completion

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to trigger a pipeline on completion of another pipeline:

1. Leverage web activity at the end and trigger the pipeline run via REST API
2. use copy activity at the end and generate a blank file and have event/blob trigger enabled for the another pipeline
3. In case if the pipeline is within same ADF, use Execute pipeline activity at the end (cloned version of the pipeline)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i want to trigger the same pipeline after its own completion for example i have pipeline1 i want to trigger the pipeline1 after pipeline1 is completed like recursive